# Poker probability for 2 pairs

Tags: combinatorics

I am having a problem figuring out the probability of a 2 pair poker hand, where 2 cards are of the same rank, two of another same rank, and one of another rank from the first 4 cards. Now the probability for this is $\frac{{13 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{11 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}}{52 \choose 5}$.

My question is why can't we do $\frac{{13 \choose 3}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}}{52 \choose 5}$, since we're selecting a total of 3 ranks from the 13 total.